# Error deserializing message with Kafka Postgres Sink Connector

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

It's driving me crazy as I'm trying to sink a kafka topic into a Postgres table. Here's my setup and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is a typical message from the Kafka topic

```
{
  "flightId": "5cbc7ad25732ab0004c51c45",
  "recordedAt": "2022-03-26T18:17:11.356Z",
  "device": "iOS",
  "platform": "A5",
  "vehicleId": "621c12a9b12161009865bc5d"
}
```

Below is my `docker-compose.yaml` file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  connector:
    image: custom-connector:latest
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: ${CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "kafka-connect-group-id"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "kafka-connect-config"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "kafka-connect-offsets"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "kafka-connect-status"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: ${CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME}
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: ${CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL}
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: ${CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM}
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
      CONNECT_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "https"
      CONNECT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: "20000"
      CONNECT_RETRY_BACKOFF_MS: "500"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "https"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_MECHANISM: "PLAIN"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: "20000"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_RETRY_BACKOFF_MS: "500"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: ${CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL}
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "https"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM: "PLAIN"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: "20000"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_RETRY_BACKOFF_MS: "500"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: ${CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL}
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/u01/connectors
      CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: ${JAAS_CONFIG}
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: ${JAAS_CONFIG}
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: ${JAAS_CONFIG}
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_IGNORE: 'true'

    ports:
      - "8083:8083"

  schema-registry:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.2.1"
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: SASL_SSL://${CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: ${JAAS_CONFIG}
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
```

My connector's config file when sending a PUT request to Kafka-connect.

```
{
    "name": "test-postgres-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://******:5432/db",
        "connection.user": "******",
        "connection.password": "******",
        "topics": "test-topic",
        "table.name.format": "kafka_sink_test",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.ignore": "true",
        "name": "test-postgres-sink-connector"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "connector": "test-postgres-sink-connector",
            "task": 0
        }
    ],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

From the logs, kafka-connect is complaining:

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=test-postgres-sink-connector-0} Error converting message value in topic 'test-topic' partition 2 at offset 0 and timestamp 1647927842369: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic test-topic:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic test-topic: 

at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:119)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$4(WorkerSinkTask.java:516)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:516)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:332)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1

at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:177)

at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:235)

at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(JsonSchemaConverter.java:165)

at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:108)

... 18 more

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!

at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:250)

at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:112)

... 21 more

[2022-03-26 18:11:31,779] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=test-postgres-sink-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:516)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:332)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic test-topic: 

at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:119)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$4(WorkerSinkTask.java:516)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)

... 13 more

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1

at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:177)

at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:235)

at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(JsonSchemaConverter.java:165)

at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:108)

... 18 more

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!

at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:250)

at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:112)

... 21 more

[2022-03-26 18:11:31,780] INFO Stopping task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask)

[2022-03-26 18:11:31,781] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-test-postgres-sink-connector-0, groupId=test-postgres-sink-connector] Revoke previously assigned partitions test-topic-0, test-topic-1, test-topic-2, test-topic-3, test-topic-4, test-topic-5 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

[2022-03-26 18:11:31,781] INFO [Consumer clientId=test-postgres-sink-connector-0, groupId=test-postgres-sink-connector] Member test-postgres-sink-connector-0-89225797-cac6-41f5-9373-bbd16bc8a1b6 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator b2-pkc-2396y.us-east-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

[2022-03-26 18:11:31,783] INFO [Consumer clientId=test-postgres-sink-connector-0, groupId=test-postgres-sink-connector] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

[2022-03-26 18:11:31,783] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-test-postgres-sink-connector-0, groupId=connect-test-postgres-sink-connector] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

[2022-03-26 18:11:32,284] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)

[2022-03-26 18:11:32,285] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)

[2022-03-26 18:11:32,286] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)

[2022-03-26 18:11:32,316] INFO App info kafka.consumer for connector-test-postgres-sink-connector-0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a typical message from the Kafka topic

Your data has no schema, so you cannot use `JsonSchemaConverter`. Plus, the JDBC Sink **requires** a schema. [JDBC Sink Deep Dive](https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/)

Since it is has no schema, and specifically didn't use the JSONSchema serializer with the Confluent Schema Registry, then you are getting `Unknown magic byte!` error from that Converter. Instead, you'll need to instead use the regular `JSONConverter` class (not prefixed with `io.confluent`, but rather `org.apache.kafka`). But as stated, `value.converter.schemas.enable` must be `true`.

More info - [Converter Deep Dive](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/)

Comment: Hey @OneCricketeer, sorry, an old thread but hope you can help me with a similar issue. I’m trying to sync MongoDB with Postgres by debezium.io (or whatever other means it might be, perhaps just plain Kafka Connector). Will it be possible to do so without schema? I mean the schema from MongoDB might change unexpectedly and I don’t want to maintain those schemas accordingly in the kafka topics.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same thing. How do I provide the schema with my data when I produce it? There is a schema for my topic and the data follows the schema, I thought that would be enough.

Comment: @TomasJansson When you use `JsonSchemaSerializer` (or Avro or Protobuf) on a producer, there is a schema already defined with each message. Otherwise, to use JSON, see linked blog post about the usage of `schema` and `payload` JSON fields for usage with `JsonConverter`. Plain JSON has no schema; it is a hashmap/dictionary where no field or its value is guaranteed across multiple records. If that is what you want in your database, use a document database, not a relational/columnar that has strict types... That's JDBC Connect's limitation.

Comment: Not sure I follow @OneCricketeer. So you are saying it isn't enough with a schema on the topic? In my other simpler example I use the datagen to produce data to another topic, and the data that comes out is only the data with no schema attach to it, and that works just fine. Is it that it is more"flat" that makes it work?

Comment: No I configured another topic using the same schema as for the one that works... but adding that topic to the sink connector didn't work. So, one topic where I can produce values which are written to postgres through the connector and another that fails and I sort of create the same thing... the only different thing is that the data in the one that works comes from the datagen source connector

Comment: I think I get it now. What you’re saying is that the one that works is because the producer Connecta a schema to it, correct? Where do I see that schema? Since I can’t see it or a reference to it in the value or header. How do I replicate that behavior since everything fails when I try to produce just a json to the topic. I guess I need to provide a reference somehow to my schema in schema registry.

Comment: @TomasJansson  Topics don't have schemas. Records built from serializers do, but it's only a numeric ID, a foreign key to the registry, which yes, is the reference you need, and not the full schema text. Search "Confluent Wire format". Subjects in the Registry are only loosely tied to the topics in Kafka. Please create a new post and give your connector configs if you have any specific issues

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thank you for comments, I did manage to figure it out. You can actually  provide the full schema if needed, but easier with referencing the id of a schema that is in a registry. What do you mean with a topic doesn't have schema, why can you provide one for a topic then? I know it isn't enforced by default, but I think enforcing a schema is also possible.

Comment: @TomasJansson The Registry has subjects. Kafka topics hold only bytes. The Converter settings used in Connect are the bridge between the two. Topics, _by themselves_, have no schema.